# Dynamic programming with dicts - python

Tags: python, combinations, dynamic-programming

I have a `list` of `dict`s; I get the indices and get the combination of indices using `itertools.combinations`.

```
list_of_dict = [{1: 'a', 2:'b', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}, 
                {1: 'b', 2:'b', 3: 'a', 4: 'd'},
                {1: 'a', 2:'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'd'},
                {1: 'c', 2:'a', 3: 'd', 4: 'b'}]
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3]
combinations = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), 
                (0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3), 
                (0, 1, 2, 3)]
```

Now I define a `merge` function that takes 2 `dict`s implements my logic of merge and returns a single `dict`. I perform merge on all elements of `combinations`.

The calls to `merge` happen as follows:

```
candidates = {}
for p in combinations:
    n = 1
    temp_p = None
    c = None
    while (n < (len(p) - 2)):
        c = tuple(list(p)[0:-n]) 
        if c in candidates:
            temp_p = candidates[c]
            break
        else: 
            n += 1
    if temp_p:
        p1 = temp_p
        p2 = p[len(c)]
        candidate[p] = merge(list_of_dict[p1], list_of_dict[p2])
    else:
        candidates[p] = merge(list_of_dict[p[0]], list_of_dict[p[1]])
```

Logic: As we can see, I can reuse the output of `merge(0, 1)` when I calculate `merge(0, 1, 2)`; i.e. `merge(0, 1, 2) = merge( merge(0,1), 2)`. Similarly for `merge(0, 1, 2, 3)` I can reuse `merge(0, 1, 2)`.

Questions:

1. I am not completely sure if the above chunk of code does exactly
   what is described in "Logic".
2. Is there an elegant and efficient way to do the above?

Edit: 
Merge function does the following. 
If d1[k] == d2[k] it adds d1[k] to the new dict to be returned else adds  None. 
So from the example given:

`merge(0,1)` should return : `{1: None, 2: 'b', 3: None, 4: 'd'}`

and

`merge(0, 1, 2)` becomes merge `merge({1: None, 2: 'b', 3: None, 4: 'd'}, {1: 'a', 2:'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'd'})` and should return `{1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: 'd'}`

This process continues till all combination of dicts are merged.

The question is especially important when we don't know the initial number of such dictionaries presented to the algorithm.

Comment: What exactly your merge is doing ? And could you show define of function ? Also, what is your expected output in this example ?

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov Added the description of merge and an example output. Thanks in advance for helping out :-)

Comment: I will update my answer ASAP to fit your requirement. Btw, is this important for `merge` accept indicies as aguments or they could be dictionaries, as i've already implemented?

Comment: The actual size of the dictionaries are too large, hence I have used indices in my implementation. Thank you again!

Comment: Hey, i've just updated my answer with explanation. Sorry, if you met mistakes, english is not my native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will fit all your requirements:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge(d1, d2, *dicts):
    new_dict = defaultdict()
    new_dict.update(d1.copy())

    for key, value in d2.items():
        if value != new_dict[key]:
            new_dict[key] = None

    if dicts:
        new_dict = merge(new_dict, *dicts)

    return new_dict


for comb in combinations:
    print(merge(*map(list_of_dict.__getitem__, comb)))
```

First of all, I left passing dictionaries to `merge`, because `dict` is mutable object, so in this case only its reference in memory is passed to function. You can easily check it with `id` function. So, since this solution is more readable than gathering dictionaries from list by indexes - it's more pythonic.

Secondary, I used `copy` of first dictionary passed to `merge`, so original one is left unmodified for other combinations.

Also as you can see, instead of `dict` I used `defaultdict` from `collections` package, so if your `d1` and `d2` have different keys - you can skip checking if key exist in `new_dict`.

And last one: `map(list_of_dict.__getitem__, comb)` - this will return generator object ( for python 3.x ) with items from `list_of_dict`, which indexes in `comb`. Wildcard before ( * ) `map` means *unpack as arguments*, so, without actually creating new list or tuple ( and unpack it afterwards ) - it just yields items ( in our case references to dictionaries in list ) as `merge` arguments.

Thats it.

Provided code will print this:

```
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: 'b', 3: None, 4: 'd'})
defaultdict(None, {1: 'a', 2: None, 3: None, 4: 'd'})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: 'd'})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: 'd', 4: None})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: 'd'})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None})
defaultdict(None, {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None})
```

Also, i've tested this code on list of 20 dictionaries ( each dictionary len = 10000 ) and i've got next timings:

1. generating list of dicts: `15.96887145599976`
2. apply merge to each indexes combination ( 1012 in total ): `15.630234674000349`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! that really helps!

Comment: @okkhoy glad that I could help